# How does enabling instant file initialization lead to information disclosure (when SQL server encrypts the data at rest)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

How does this lead to information disclosure when SQL server encrypts the data at rest?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Trying to clarify a bit:

The danger isn't that somebody else will get to SQL Server's sensitive data (the data in your databases).

It is the other way around.

Say you have an Excel sheet with sensitive information in it. This document is deleted. The bits are still on disk. SQL Server grows a database file and gets that disk space. Somebody uses `DBCC PAGE` to "spy" on that sensitive Excel data.

See for example https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/instant-initialization-what-why-and-how/

Comment: I've never thought of it that way before, but that's a very interesting example!

Answer (score 2):

First off, SQL Server does not encrypt data by default, neither at rest nor at move. TLS/SSL can be used to encrypt data at move, at rest can either use TDE or column-based encryption. What's more, one can use disk encryption such as Bitlocker to protect the disks against physical attacks. Always Encrypted is also an option for cases in which one doesn't trust the environment. All encryption features must be enabled by admin, as it's never as simple as clicking "encrypt" button. The most complex thing to manage for encryption is the key management - without good key management process, there is no way to successfully restore data from backups.

Notice that the help text says *may*, not that it *will*. The idea about IFI enabling information disclosure is a bit theoretical, as it requires malicious actor to have access to the system. Anyway, the idea is that when SQL Server IFI-allocates a block from the disk, SQL admin could look at the fresh non-overwriten parts of the disk for data that used to be there. This is not a big deal for many systems in which SQL admins have local server admin or even domain admin permissions, but in finely-grained (read: siloed) environments it may be a cause for concern. Take a look at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-instant-file-initialization?view=sql-server-ver15#security-considerations) too.

Honestly, if you are worried that your SQL Server administrator is snooping around, hire an admin you do trust. SQL Server sysadmin can do much worse things than looking at deleted data that used to be on a disk.

Comment: But my question is - if the data is encrypted at rest, then can the information disclosure still happen because of IFI?

Comment: It depends on how encrypt at rest is done.

Answer (score 1):

> How does this lead to information disclosure when SQL server encrypts the data at rest?

It doesn't.  SQL Server encrypts data at rest using Transparent Data Encryption (TDE), and TDE disables Instant File Initialization.

> Some feature usage, such as Transparent Data Encryption (TDE), can
> prevent Instant File Initialization.

[Database Instant File Initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-instant-file-initialization?view=sql-server-ver15#enable-instant-file-initialization)